# Wifi Channels and frequencies?

Tags: wireless-networking

i really stuck and didn't understand anything about how WLAN Channels and frequencies actually work .. how it changes channel while the router doesn't move .. and what does it mean 22MHZ and 40MHZ in every channel? please can anybody answer me and thank you so much !!

Comment: You need to be more specific please.

Comment: I've edited my question, please leave an answer and thanks a lot!

Comment: Its still unclear, all channels are are slightly different frequencies within the specified range (2.4ghz or 5ghz depending on your router), only reason to change channel is if that channel is crowded due to other devices using that same channel within the Ghz range of the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how it changes channel while the router doesn't move

"Channels" are just names for pre-assigned radio frequencies, e.g. "channel 12" is the name for 2.417 GHz (all 1–14 are in 2.4 GHz range), channel 116 is 5.58 GHz, and so on. (See [list of Wi-Fi channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels).)

The AP or router doesn't have to *move* in order to switch channels; it only tunes its transmitter /receiver for the new frequency. It's no different from switching channels in a FM radio or a TV.

> what does it mean 22MHZ and 40MHZ in every channel

Actual Wi-Fi signals aren't sent at a single frequency – they use a range of frequencies around it, and "20 MHz" / "40 MHz" describe the channel width, i.e. how large the frequency range actually is. The greater channel width, the faster you can transfer data, but at the cost of

For example, channel 12 with channel width of 20 MHz would mean 2417 MHz as the center and ±10 MHz to both sides, that is, actually 2407–2427 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

There are several channels that you can use in the 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz band for wifi.  Each channel is just a slightly different frequency within the band.  I think when you mention the 20Mhz and 40 Mhz you are referring to the bandwidth of the channel you are using.  Bandwidth refers to how much of the band you are using to transfer data.

Typically, a 40 Mhz bandwidth can transfer more data, but it may cause more interference or receive more interference since it uses more of the band.  Also, older devices may only be able to work with a 20 Mhz bandwidth.

Here is a good article that explains how to choose which bandwidth to use: http://routerguide.net/setting-up-20-mhz-or-40-mhz-bandwidth-how-to-improve-wifi-network-performance/

Answer (score 0):

On the wiki page you can see in the graph how each channel can have a 22MHz width accross the legal range of frequencies allowed for these types of devices:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels

So there can be several devices in close proximity, but if they are using different channels, they will not interfere with each other.